# QML ApplicationWindow: set minimum size to fit content

Tags: qt, qml, menubar

I would like to set the minimum width and height of my QML Application window, so that the content item is fully visible (not clipped).

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100

    title: "test"

    minimumWidth: circle.width
    minimumHeight: circle.height // + menuBar.height

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: circle
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "red"
        radius: width * 0.5
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, setting the minimum width works fine. The minimum height seems to be off by the height of the menu bar. The problem is, adding something like `menuBar.height` does not work as this property does not exist.

So the question is: how do I set the size of the ApplicationWindow, so that the content item (given by `width`/`height` or `implicitWidth`/`implicitHeight`) is not clipped?

Note: In reality, instead of a red circle, the content item serves as a game canvas, which I would like to resize dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always with the old `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` the only way to help yourself is, to look at the (undocumented/internal) properties. For the `MenuBar` those are:

- objectName
- menus
- **__contentItem**
- __parentWindow
- __isNative
- style
- __style
- __menuBarComponent
- objectNameChanged
- menusChanged
- nativeChanged
- contentItemChanged
- styleChanged
- __styleChanged
- __menuBarComponentChanged

**__contentItem** seems to be interesting, and it features a `height` - as soon as it is instantiated.

So we can define the height of the `ApplicationWindow` as such:

```
minimumHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
               + (menuBar.__contentItem ? menuBar.__contentItem.height : 0)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This results in a binding loop warning for property "minimumHeight". at least for 5.12 and 5.15. That's Controls 2.X though